# Appium IOS SendKey not working

Tags: ios, appium

I am using Appium to automate a Hybrid application. Selenium method sendkey is working fine in Android. However sendkey is not working in IOS. Hence to make it work I am using javascript executor to set value and then fire the change event.

This has really brought down my confidence in appium for automating hybrid app. I would like to know whether there is any way to make 'sendkey' work in IOS. Also is it a common issue.

Comment: What have you tried?  What errors are you getting?  We need some more info to know how to help you.

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far and error message you are getting!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("YOUR X-PATH");
element.click();
element.sendKeys("your input string");
```

Comment: After wasting 3 hours googling for solutions, This simple trick worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well for iOS you should set capability "sendKeyStrategy" to "grouped" or "setValue".

Refer http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.3.4/?ruby#ios-only

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working with iOS simulator, I think on clicking the text field the keyboard failed to display and hence its failing to enter text to the application. Please check your simulator setting that the trigger simulator keyboard is checked.

Hope this fix your issue.